# Angular subscribe not saving data in array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to save data from an HTTP.GET inside an array using subscribe so I can put this data inside a Highchart pie. I can't seem to make it work, but I know i'm getting the data since while debugging I could see data during the subscribe inside my variable, but it's almost like the data gets deleted or happens after.

Sorry for probably beginner mistakes.

I've tried so many things I can't even remember them all.
But right now i'm stuck with this:

```
graph: any[] = [] //tried using it as an Object too
```

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dashboardService
    .getGraph()
    .subscribe(graph => {
      this.graph = graph
      console.log(this.graph) //read note A
      //this.ageOptions = this.graph
      })  
  console.log(this.graph) //read note B
  }
```

note A when I check this inside console, I actually get {skills distribution: {…}, ages distribution: {…}, experience distribution: {…}} which is what I want

note B, When I check this other instead, I get empty -> I don't want empty array.

```
[]
```

Comment: Your subscription has not completed by the time you log B. See the duplicate linked question.